# How can I create a shortcut to toggle javascript on/off in mobile Safari on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, safari, settings, automation, javascript

How can I create a shortcut to quickly toggle JavaScript off/on on my iPhone?
I prefer to read the news with JavaScript disabled and then other websites, which typically require it to work, with it turned back on. Digging through the preferences to change this setting is tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the iPhone create and use a shortcut for Safari advanced options:

- open Shortcuts on iOS and select the + to create a new one;
- give it a name (eg "toggle-js");
- choose add action then from the "Web" options select Open URL;
- use the URL in quotes here: "prefs:root=SAFARI&path=ADVANCED";
- select the adjustments icon at the top and choose add to home screen;
- now use the shortcut and toggle the javascript option as desired when the advanced options opens;

find more settings URL info here: https://www.macstories.net/ios/a-comprehensive-guide-to-all-120-settings-urls-supported-by-ios-and-ipados-13-1/